# Parse list of Pydantic classes from list of strings

Tags: python, pydantic

I'd like to parse a `Polygon` with a list of `Points` out of the following data:

```json
{"points": ["0|0", "1|0", "1|1"]}
```

I naively thought I could do something like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Point(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: int

    @validator("x", "y", pre=True)
    def get_coords(cls, value, values):
        x, y = value.split("|")
        values["x"] = x
        values["y"] = y


class Polygon(BaseModel):
    points: list[Point]
```

But when I try and parse my "JSON" string I get an error complaining that `value is not a valid dict`:

```py
>>> Polygon.parse_obj({"points": ["0|0", "1|0", "1|1"]})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 511, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.parse_obj
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 3 validation errors for Polygon
points -> 0
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
points -> 1
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
points -> 2
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

How can I parse interesting objects out of this dull list of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pydantic v2.0 it is possible to directly create custom conversions from arbitrary data to a `BaseModel`. This allows to define the conversion once for the specific `BaseModel` to automatically make containing classes support the conversion.

The trick is to use a [`@model_validator(mode="before")`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/functional_validators/#pydantic.functional_validators.model_validator) to parse input before creating the model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator


class Point(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: int

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def from_literal(cls, data: Any) -> Any:
        """Automatically parse 'x|y' literals"""
        if isinstance(data, str):
            # optionally validate literal
            assert data.count("|") == 1, "literal requires one | separator"
            x, y = data.split("|")
            # field type conversion can be handled by pydantic
            return dict(x=x, y=y)
        return data
```

Notably, we only have to parse the input into fields that Pydantic can convert to the final field type. This also allows to combine multiple models that define their own literal syntax.
In addition, we can optionally validate the literal using the usual Pydantic means of `assert`ing assumptions. Also, we should pass through other data to still support instances and data dictionaries.

---

This definition is sufficient to parse even nested literals automatically, while still accepting explicit instances and data:

```
# these create the same objects
print(Polygon.model_validate({"points": ["0|0", "1|0", "1|1"]}))
print(Polygon.model_validate({"points": ["0|0", Point(x=1, y=0), {"x": 1, "y": 1}]}))
# validation rejects the invalid literal
print(Polygon.model_validate({"points": ["0|0", "1|0", "1|1|1"]}))
```

`model_validate` replaces `parse_obj` in Pydantic v2.0. However, this still works with `parse_obj`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem we need to overcome here is that `Polygon.points` gets a list of `str` *not* a list of `Point` as expected; so this is where we should intervene:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Point(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: int


class Polygon(BaseModel):
    points: list[Point]

    @validator("points", pre=True, each_item=True)
    def each_element_should_be_a_point(cls, v):
        coords = v.split("|")
        point = Point(x=coords[0], y=coords[1])
        return point


poly = Polygon.parse_obj({"points": ["0|0", "1|0", "1|1"]})
```