# Parse list of strings with different types

Tags: python, model, pydantic

I need to parse a list of strings where strings are heterogeneous type.
Ex:
{data : ["+91-8827222222", "int_val", "str_val", "+91-8827222223", "+91-8827222224"]}

i want to verify above list, but not able to get exact answer of my question anywhere, I followed few references but it didn't helped.
[Parse list of Pydantic classes from list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71400057/parse-list-of-pydantic-classes-from-list-of-strings)
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/fr/tutorial/body-nested-models/

I Need something like this,

```
class mobile_no(data):
# validation code

class UserData(BaseModel):
   data: List[mobile_no, str, int]
```

Will appreciate your help :)

Comment: @tdelaney its always going to be mobile number only, i have added the format

Comment: @tdelaney how do i add a series of regex? can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from typing import List, Union
import pydantic
import re

class phone(str):

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, str):
            raise TypeError('string required')
        if not re.match(r'^\+\d{2}\-\d{10}$', v):
            raise ValueError('invalid phone format')
        return cls(v)

class UserData(pydantic.BaseModel):
    data: List[Union[phone,str]]

user_data = UserData(data=["+91-8827222222", "int_val", "str_val", "+91-8827222223", "+91-8827222224"])

for item in user_data.data:
    print(item, type(item), isinstance(item, phone), isinstance(item, str))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am getting following error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type' "

Comment: i also tried with "data: List[str or phone]" but its only validating the first datatype i.e. str,

Comment: @DmUser because you have an older version of python that does not support `|` Union

Comment: @DmUser when you do an `or` statement it does or logic and returns the first true element, which both are True, but str goes first. You must do Union. I changed the code to run on your version of python, try it out.

Comment: Hey, Thank you so so much, its working fine and i am unblocked now. Thanks again :)